# PHP form and populate dropdown issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to MySQL and populate the data to Dropdown. Here is my code. Some reason dropdown is not getting populated. Please suggest.

Here is the code.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$mysqli_connection = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
if (isset($_POST['Submit_1'])) {
    require 'submit.php';
    require 'validate.php';
    if ($form_errors = validate_form()) {
        show_form($form_errors);
    }
    else
    {
        form_submit_1();
    }
}
else
{
    show_form();
}
function show_form($errors = '')
{
    // were there any errors?  
    if ($errors) {
        //show errors
    }

    ?>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT id, code FROM table1";
    $result11 = $mysqli_connection->query($sql);
    echo " <select name = \"state1\" id=\"state1\">";
    while ($row = $result11->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value = $row[id]>$row[code]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
} // End of show_form()
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part:

```
echo "<option value = $row[id]>$row[code]</option>";
```

Is not valid, it should be something like this:

```
echo "<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['code']}</option>";
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. If I move the dropdown code logic above the function show_form($errors = ''), it works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to escape from the string back to the PHP layer.

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".$row['code']."</option>";
```

That way you'll concatanate the PHP value of the variables with the string elements you're creating.